# Acceder a clave dentro de objeto json

Tags: javascript, object

Tengo la siguiente consulta
Por medio de un `ajax` obtengo este `json`

```
{"messageList":{"USER_DATA":{"nombre":"pablo","apellido":"santamarina"},"SESION_DATA":{"isUserLogin":"true"}}}
```

lo que quiero hacer ahora es recorrer los objetos dentro de `messageList` y acceder a la clave de cada uno pero idealmente sin un `for` in
Por ahora tengo este código pero no estoy accediendo todavía al valor que necesito

```
ServicesController.prototype.newMessageInvoice = function(dataSource)
{
    var msgList = dataSource.messageList;

    for (var message in msgList) {

        var message = msgList[message];


    }
}
```

aclaro, necesito acceder a los valores de las claves, osea que el retorno sea por ejemplo "`USER_DATA`" o "`SESION_DATA`", ya que tengo que evaluar de que tipo es dicho mensaje.

entiendo que la forma seria hacer algo así:

```
Object.keys(message)[0]
```

pero no me estoy parando correctamente dentro del objeto

Answer (score 3):

Bueno espero que le sirva si alguien se topa con el mismo problma, ya lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera

```
ServicesController.prototype.newMessageInvoice = function(dataSource)
{
    var msgList = dataSource.messageList;
    var msgsKeys = Object.keys(msgList);

    for(var i=0; i< msgsKeys.length; i++)
    {
        alert(msgsKeys[i]);
        var msgType     = msgsKeys[i];
        var msgContent  = dataSource.messageList[msgType];
        alert(JSON.stringify(msgContent));

    }
}
```